# Java identifying generic container element type

Tags: java, generics

What I am trying to achieve is a map of generic lists that I can then serialize. I have achieved this but probably not in the best way, anyway I don't understand one point which I describe further below.
Basically I don't see how mClass ends up being "[Ljava.lang.Integer" i.e. Integer[] and not only "java.lang.Integer".

Edit: In order to make my question clear. I don't understand why mClass is **Integer[]** when I instantiated the class with GenericArrayData< Integer>, i.e. I was expecting **Integer**. Thanks

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
    import junit.framework.Assert;
    import org.junit.Test;

    public class TestDataCollectorTest {

      public class GenericArrayData<T> {

        public Class mClass;
        public CopyOnWriteArrayList<T[]> data;

        public GenericArrayData(Class<T> type) {
          mClass = type;
          data = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        }
      }

      public <T> void logGenericArrayData(HashMap<String, GenericArrayData> map, String tag, T[] obj) {
        if (map.containsKey(tag)) {
          GenericArrayData<T> d = map.get(tag);
          d.data.add(obj);
          return;
        }

        System.out.println("Adding log entry named\"" + tag + "\"");
        Class k = obj.getClass();
        GenericArrayData<T> d = new GenericArrayData<T>(k);
        d.data.add(obj);
        map.put(tag, d);
      }

      @Test
      public void basics() {

        HashMap<String, GenericArrayData> map = new HashMap<>();
        GenericArrayData<Integer> list = new GenericArrayData<>(Integer.class);
        Integer[][] inputData = new Integer[10][10];
        for (int i = 0; i < inputData.length; ++i) {
          inputData[i] = new Integer[10];
          for (int j = 0; j < inputData[0].length; ++j) {
            inputData[i][j] = i * 100 + j;
          }

          logGenericArrayData(map, "integers", inputData[i]);
        }

        Assert.assertEquals(1, map.size());
        GenericArrayData d = map.get("integers");
        Assert.assertEquals(10, d.data.size());

        System.out.println(d.mClass);
        Integer[] ia = new Integer[0];
        System.out.println(ia.getClass());
        Assert.assertTrue(ia.getClass() == d.mClass);  // I don't quite understand
        Integer[][] outputData = new Integer[d.data.size()][];
        outputData = (Integer[][]) d.data.toArray(outputData);
        Assert.assertEquals(inputData.length, outputData.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < inputData.length; ++i) {
          Assert.assertEquals(inputData[i], outputData[i]);
        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: Are you asking what `[Ljava.lang.Integer;` represents?

Comment: You passed `k` in  `new GenericArrayData<T>(k);`, where `k` is the `Class` object for an `Integer[]`. And `ia` is also an `Integer[]`. I'm confused what you're asking.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is correct. You create `GenericArrayData` with the class of `Integer` and this is what you get printed at the end. Voting to close.

Comment: Sorry if it's obvious but I don't understand why when I declare GenericArrayData<Integer>, mClass ends up representing Integer[]

Comment: The `T` in your `logGenericArrayData` method is completely independent from the class `T`. Regardless, you've passed an `Integer[]` array value as that last argument. You then called `getClass` on that value and assigned its result to `mClass`. That's all completely unrelated to the generic class parameter `T`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis oh ok I get my error, somehow I didn't realize that I wasnt using the "list" variable at all.. I thought this was some weird type deduction in Java. My bad, thanks.